# Is there a better way to pass string output from jq to bash?

Tags: jq

I’ve just discovered jq and been really loving it. One thing I find myself doing a lot though stuff like:

```
result=$(jq --raw-output '.some | .filters // ""')
if [[ $result ]]; then
    foo
else
    bar
fi
```

The default to an empty string seems to play more nicely with bash "truthiness" than e.g. `if [[ $result != "null" ]]`, and raw-output is usually necessary to store just the resultant string in a variable. My question is, I’m using these two tweaks so consistently in scripts, is there perhaps a better way to achieve the same functionality? Or would it make sense (as a possible enhancement to jq) to be able to set a couple env vars to control this behavior for the duration of the script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `-e` flag that will make `jq` return exit code `0` if the last output value was neither `false` or `null` so then your logic may become:

```
result=$(jq -e -r '.some | .filters') && foo || bar
```